# Using cache operator for Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am following some tutorials from angular-university and in a video they suggest to use `cache()` operator to avoid multiple requests. So I tried with the following:

```
this.posts$ = this.postsService.savePost(post)
    .switchMap(() => this.postsService.getPosts())
    .publishReplay(1)
    .refCount();
```

and it works but I prefer `cache()` instead of `publishReplay`
The naive way to achieve this is:

```
this.postsService.savePost(post)
    .subscribe(() => this.postsService.getPosts())
```

but it is not kind of reactive.

So I prefer to use `cache` but I could not find this on the `add` operators.

Currently I am using `rxjs: 5.4.3`.

So, is `cache` supported by the version I am currently using?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache is gone as of version 5.0.0 according to [the changlog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-rc1-2016-10-11)